# Playing a tone from a custom memory buffer and not from a file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to develop an application for the iPhone that creates a custom memory buffer and plays a pure tone of a sine wave (like beep beeep beeeep).

I saw this code in the forum:

http://www.omnigroup.com/mailman/archive/macosx-dev/2000-May/014070.html

and I find it very close to what I'm looking for, but it is for the Mac, and that causes many compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is look at the AVFoundation framework documentation in the developers portal to learn how to use the audio subsystem on the iphone. There is sample code available, and coupled with your ability to generate audio, you should be able to at least get closer to your eventual goal, if not get all the way there.